# Invalidate queries with multiple mutations in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a delete mutation which deletes a role from database once at a time.

```
import { axios, getEndpoint } from "@/api"
import { ResponseData } from "@/api/types"
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { rolesKey } from "./useRolesQuery"

export const deleteRoleFn = (id: number | string) => {
  return axios.delete<ResponseData<[]>>(getEndpoint("role", { id }))
}

export const useDeleteRole = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: deleteRoleFn,
    onSuccess: (data, id) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: rolesKey })
      queryClient.removeQueries({ queryKey: getRoleKey(id) })
    }
  })
}
```

The parent component which uses `useDeleteRole` hook might want to delete 10 roles simultaneously. So there is a `for` loop that will call `mutate` 10 times in a row. The thing is, I don't want to call `queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: rolesKey })` 10 times and only once. How can I achieve this behavior once all the mutations are settled? Also some of them might fail and if even one of them succeeds, I must invalidate `rolesKey` query.
Another thing is I don't want to do something like below, since it uses spread operator and I might create additional renders or unwanted `useEffect/useMemo/useCallback` calls if used inside the dependency array.

```
export const useDeleteRole = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: deleteRoleFn,
    // mutationKey: deleteRoleKey,
    onSuccess: (data, id) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: rolesKey })
      // queryClient.removeQueries({ queryKey: getRoleKey(id) }) TODO
    }
  })

  const multiMutate = () => {
    // Handle multi mutation and invalidate with Promise.allSettled
  }
  
  return {...mutation, multiMutate}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think, what you need is query-matching https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-invalidation#query-matching-with-invalidatequeries


Look into 'predicate' as well

Answer (score 0):

You can make one mutation that fires multiple delete requests and returns a single Promise with `Promise.all`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, is it a good pattern to return a multi mutate function from my custom query hooks which uses `Promise.all`? Also, is it possible to do optimistic updates with this pattern?